# How to animate activity side out on finish() event/calendar activity - Android Java

Tags: android, events, animation, android-activity, slide

I'm using a slide in and out animation to switch between my activity's.
But it doesn't work all the way on the event/calendar activity.

Is there a way of setting an animation on the event/calendar activity when making an appointment is cancelled?

This is the code i'm using now:

```
public void addEventToCalendar(Calendar startTime, Calendar endTime, String eventTitle){

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra("beginTime", startTime.getTimeInMillis());
    intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
    intent.putExtra("endTime", endTime.getTimeInMillis());
    intent.putExtra("title", eventTitle);
    startActivity(intent); //Starts activity to make an appointment
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left);
}
```

The animation when starting the activity works fine, but when the user cancels the appointment the activity will just fade out by default. i would rather like to slide it out en the underlying activity to slide in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not make any changes to other applications activities such as adding animation but if you want to add some animation into your activity when its finished, try to write this code in onBackPress():

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_left,R.anim.slide_in_right);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: In which onBackPressed() do i put it? since i can't adjust the code of activity started by  `intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");` because it's a native android activity...right?

Comment: I got it.
You cant add animation to other applications activities.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle it on onBackpressed() method in an activity.

Just add `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out_left,R.anim.slide_in_right);` in your `onBackPressed()` method.

That's all.